# How can I set up the time to run in Python Script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to run my python script to run on specific time.

For example, I don't want it to run at 12 AM to 3 AM. 
So it will only run 3AM to 11PM and sleep for 3 hours and run again after 3 AM.

I don't want to kill the PID if it runs while it reached 12 AM.. I want it to finish and go to sleep if the time is between 12 AM and 3 AM..

for Shell Script:

```
 while true
 do
       curr_time=`date +"%H%M%S"`
       if [ $curr_time -ge 235000 -a $curr_time -le 030000 ]
       then
            sleep 12000 
            #Going to check time before 12AM so that it can stop before 12
            #Sleep for little more than 3hours since it might stop before 3AM
       else
            break;
       fi
 done`
```

But main question is.. I can't think of a way to do this in python. 
Also, is there a way to set the sleeping time automatically wake up at 3AM? instead of me setting how long it should sleep?

Comment: Use a scheduler like `cron` for this instead of handling it manually?

Comment: I am trying not to use Cron and just implemented in the script so that who ever use this program, they can just execute the set up program instead of thinking or setting the different schedule

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to stick with "Don't do that" as my answer here. But <shrug>.

Comment: When I used my original shell script with the above program worked fine and it was very helpful for what we are doing.. but now we need some python stuff.. so I am trying to do the same in Python.

Comment: Plus... there are more conditions then what I mentioned.. so `cron` doesn't work for us

Comment: Any extra, non-time based, conditions can be in the script itself to prevent it from running. This is what `logrotate` does to control what it rotates and when despite being run from cron daily (or even more often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should be using an existing scheduler, but if you must sleep yourself, the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module makes it fairly straightforward:

```
import datetime
while 1:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour < 3:
        at_3 = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),
                                         datetime.time(3))
        to_sleep = (at_3 - now).seconds
        time.sleep(to_sleep)

    # do the work ...
```

Comment: why is it while 1? also how is this break out if it is not in between the time? on shell script there is a break command that does that but this one I don't fully understand it..

Comment: @PETER `while 1` means loop forever, which I understood the program was to do. Breaking out of the loop should happen only when there is no more work to be done.

Comment: sorry.. it shouldn't run forever. my example was just not running 12 to 3 but it should actually SLEEP at 12~3am and STOP after 8 AM even if there are more works to do.. so it does not run 24/7.. thats why I want to know how I can break out..

Comment: @PETER Then simply `break` if now.hour >= 8 or whatever it is you need. The above code should be easy to adapt to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or build-in [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) in python.